# Second Monitor Issues on Lenovo W530 running Ubuntu 14.04.1

Tags: 14.04, graphics, lenovo, nvidia-optimus

I have a Lenovo W530 with Nvidia Optimus technology running Ubuntu 14.04. I am using the Nouveau drivers and experiencing problems when connecting a second monitor to the VGA port. I would like to be able to use a second monitor without issues where I'm experiencing the following;

**Configuration 1**

In the BIOS I have set 'Nvidia Optimus' and have the following kernel parameters;

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force"
```

In that configuration the mouse on the 'Built-in Display' flickers and disappears (*Note I do not have an unknown monitor in System Settings -> Display) and the windows on the second monitor appear streaky/fuzzy sometimes (most of the time they're fine). Without plugging into a second monitor there are no issues however, once a monitor is attached to the laptop the machine will crash and it will not go into hibernate when the lid is closed. I have to poweroff as the machine becomes unstable.

**Configuration 2**

In the BIOS I have set 'discrete' and have the following kernel paramenters;

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force video.use_native_backlight=1 acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

I have also tried

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

And

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force video.use_native_backlight=1"
```

Without the *acpi_backlight=vendor* the machine will hang once the brightness is adjusted on the laptop (F8/F9). With the kernel parameter the brightness adjustment doesn't work.

I've tried installing the nvidia-current drivers but they don't pick up the second monitor at all...

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this issue requires changes to BIOS settings. Under 'Display' set the graphics to

> Graphics Device [**Discrete Graphics**]

Under 'Virtualization';

> Intel (R) Virtualization Technology [**Enabled**]
>
> Intel (R) VT-d Feature [**Disabled**]

I also added the following to /etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash thinkpad-acpi.brightness_enable=1"
```

but I don't think it was necessary...

Comment: Thanks a lot. This finally solved my crashing when using the discrete card on ARchlinux